# C# Parse xml Attriubte with name a and write it with name b

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a XML dom

```
<xml>
<ElementA/>
<xml>
```

Now my xml changed

```
<xml>
<ElementB/>
<xml>
```

The value of ElementB an A is simular but i have a couple of files with ElementA and must migrate them to ElementB.

I'm working with XmlSerializer

Is it possible to read two nodes to one parameter and write them to one Attribute name like

```
[XmlElement("ElementB")]
[XmlElement("ElementA")] // Writing this version only somehow 
  public float Rating
  { get; set; }
```

Comment: FYI - The things you are calling "attributes" are actually *elements*.  The two are distinct concepts in XML.

Comment: you are totaly right i will change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used Linq to XML ([System.Xml.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx)) to do this sort of schema migration work in the past with great success. Your code would look something like:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("<path to input xml document>");
foreach (var element in doc.Descendants("AttributeA"))
{
    element.Name = "AttributeB";
}
doc.Save("<path to output xml document>");
```

Basically, you just read in the whole document into and XDocument, find the nodes you are looking for via Linq, manipulate their values, and the write the changed XDocument back out to disc. Then if you still want to use Xml Serialization you would read that document from disc again and continue to process like you were before.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with XML Attribute Overrides. Essentially 
you can apply XML Serialization attributes to a serializer, at runtime.

[See the MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/athddy89%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Here's some example code for using XML attribute overrides with XML serialization.

```
public class DTO
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string additionalInformation;

    [XmlElement(Order=1)]
    public DateTime stamp;

    [XmlElement(Order=2)]
    public string name;

    [XmlElement(Order=3)]
    public double value;

    [XmlElement(Order=4)]
    public int index;
}


public class OverridesDemo
{
    public void Run()
    {
        DTO dto = new DTO {
            additionalInformation = "This information will be serialized separately",
            stamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
            name = "Marley",
            value = 72.34,
            index = 7
        };

        // this will allow us to omit the xmlns:xsi namespace
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add( "", "" );

        XmlSerializer s1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DTO));

        var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent= true };

        Console.WriteLine("\nSerialize using the in-line (compile-time) attributes: ");
        using ( XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, settings))
        {
            s1.Serialize(writer, dto, ns);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0}",builder.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("\n");


        // use a default namespace
        ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        string myns = "urn:www.example.org";
        ns.Add( "", myns );

        XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

        XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();
        // override the (implicit) XmlRoot attribute
        XmlRootAttribute attr1 = new XmlRootAttribute
            {
                Namespace = myns,
                ElementName = "DTO-Annotations",
            };
        attrs.XmlRoot = attr1;

        overrides.Add(typeof(DTO), attrs);
        // "un-ignore" the first property
        // define an XmlElement attribute, for a type of "String", with no namespace
        var a2 = new XmlElementAttribute(typeof(String)) { ElementName="note", Namespace = myns };

        // add that XmlElement attribute to the 2nd bunch of attributes
        attrs = new XmlAttributes();
        attrs.XmlElements.Add(a2);
        attrs.XmlIgnore = false;

        // add that bunch of attributes to the container for the type, and
        // specifically apply that bunch to the "Label" property on the type.
        overrides.Add(typeof(DTO), "additionalInformation", attrs);

        // ignore the other properties

        // add the XmlIgnore attribute to the 2nd bunch of attributes
        attrs = new XmlAttributes();
        attrs.XmlIgnore = true;

        // add that bunch of attributes to the container for the type, and
        // specifically apply that bunch to the "Label" property on the type.
        overrides.Add(typeof(DTO), "stamp", attrs);
        overrides.Add(typeof(DTO), "name", attrs);
        overrides.Add(typeof(DTO), "value", attrs);
        overrides.Add(typeof(DTO), "index", attrs);

        XmlSerializer s2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DTO), overrides);

        Console.WriteLine("\nSerialize using the override attributes: ");
        builder.Length = 0;
        using ( XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, settings))
        {
            s2.Serialize(writer, dto, ns);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0}",builder.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
```

You can use overrides for serialization or for de-serialization.